# How to query for strings based on their length

Tags: mysql, database

create table dict {id, word varchar2(255)).

I store strings of varying lengths within the 'word' field. How do I query for the following cases:-

1. Search all words which are 4 characters in length
2. Search all words which are greater than 4 characters in length
3. Search all words which have 4-8 characters (inclusive)
4. Search all words which are lesser than 4 characters in length

Env: h2, mysql. The data consists of english words, but would like to know the limitations if you use multibyte data (e.g japanese)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dict
WHERE
  LENGTH(word) = 4 /* 1. */
  OR (LENGTH(word) > 4) /* 2. */
  OR (LENGTH(word) >=4 AND LENGTH(word) <= 8) /* 3. */
  OR (LENGTH(word) <4) /* 4. */

/* Choose the right WHERE clause, based on your case */
```

For multibyte data, you should use [CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead of `LENGTH`

Answer (score 1):

You could refine the question and explain what was not clear in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) for string functions.

[CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) docs state clearly that

> Returns the length of the string str,
>   measured in characters. A multi-byte
>   character counts as a single
>   character. This means that for a
>   string containing five two-byte
>   characters, LENGTH() returns 10,
>   whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.